# Express error handling or domain?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, uncaught-exception

I am building an app in nodejs and express. Can anybody help me to understand the difference between the following pieces of code:

```
  var app = express();
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err);
  res.render('home.ejs', {message:'Something broke!'});
  });
```

and

```
 var domain = require('domain');
 var d = domain.create();
 d.on('error', function(err) {
 console.error(err);
 res.render('home.ejs', {message:'Something broke!'});
 });
```

Are the two pieces of code alternative? If yes, which one is more reliable in order to avoid the app crashing on production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express wraps each `function (req, res, next) {}` in a try/catch.  Which catches many errors, but not async errors.  Domains catch async errors.  However catching the error and handling it are two different things.

If you next the error (aka `d.on('error', next);`) it will end up in going to express error middleware, just like in your first example.

So instead of thinking about express vs domains, think try/catch vs domains.  Express should be used to handle the error in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get async error handling working with domains with this middleware:

```
function(req,res,next){
    var d = domain.create();

    d.on('error',next)

    d.run(function(){
        next();
    })
}
```

I'm currently testing it in on my servers, but looks good for me:). I also created npm module. You can take a look at it:

[npmjs.org - express-async-error](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-async-error)

Hope this helps. :)